# How to fill horizontal space with a div responsively

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create a feed page and I want it to be totally responsive. The layout is a score on the right with a fixed width and a link on the left which should take up the rest of the horizontal space.

The code I have so far has the link just taking up the whole line and passing underneath the score div.

This will be a problem if the link title is so long that it gets cut off by the score as I can't stop the link div's width once it collides in which case I'd like to use the `text-overflow: ellipsis` feature.

My code is below along with a jsfiddle link

HTML

```
<body>
    <ul id="tracklist">
        <li class="trackwrap"> <a class="tracklink" href="#">Link 1</a>

            <p class="trackscore">x score</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#tracklist {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: white;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
.trackwrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;
    transition: 1s;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    transition: 1.5s;
}
.tracklink {
    background: red;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    left: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 24px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
.trackscore {
    background: blue;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    right: 52px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Lf8v9tn/

This needs to be responsive so I'd prefer it if answers could use `width: 100%` for the link div

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a `min-width` on your `.trackwrap` like so: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lf8v9tn/1/